# Cytoscape.js – Unable to display a graph fitting to a collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I've got a problem with displaying graph using [Cytoscape.js](http://js.cytoscape.org/). I want to display graph which fits to the viewport, let's look at [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zh1yfqt/1/). As you can see, I'm using also React. The fiddle version of the graph works well, however in my personal project, when I'll display node's labels, it breaks. Nodes are moved to the bottom of viewport. Also when I'll set

```
'text-valign': 'center'
```

to the node's labels, they are displayed below nodes. If I remove node's labels, it works ... but with labels no. What should I do? Where should I look for an error?
[image]

Comment: okay, I've solved it ... it's my written CSS which impacts it...

Answer (score 0):

css definiton

```
body > div { height: 100%; }
```

is responsible for this bug